# Truncate floated div content with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a dynamic layout in CSS that truncates text in a floated div using text-overflow: ellipsis in a way that takes into account the size of sibling elements

The layout consists of 3 divs

```
|--------------------A-------------------|
||------B------||-------C-------|        |
|| Hello world || Goodbye world |        |
||-------------||---------------|        |
|----------------------------------------|
```

- Div A: Wrapper parent
- Div B: show as much content as possible, and truncate to ellipsis if not enough space
- Div C: all of this content should always be visible. The width of this content is not fixed (but will always be <50% of the width of div A) . If the content in B is not truncated, this div should directly beside div B.

And in the case there div B should truncate text, I want it to look like:

```
|--------------------A-------------------|
||------B--------------||-------C-------||
|| Hello world this ...|| Goodbye world ||
||---------------------||---------------||
|----------------------------------------|
```

I can get the general layout set up, but my problem is I cannot trigger Div B to truncate the content when needed. My code so far:

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
}
#div-b {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#div-c {
  color: #6a7d80;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div-b">This is my really long message hello world hello world hello world </div>
  <div id="div-c">Goodbye world</div>
</div>
```

Adding a max-width to div B works, but the problem is that the content in div C does change so I cannot hardcode a max-width value that works in all cases.

I'm starting to think this isn't possible without javascript. Any ideas?

Comment: Try messing around with `display: table, table-row, table-cell`. Might work for you

Comment: I actually did. I set div B width to 1% (so column width hugged the content) and that allowed div C to align correctly. Problem is that text-overflow doesn't seem to work well in table cells

Answer (score 1):

Just use [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.w1 {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.w2 {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.div-b {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.div-c {
  color: #6a7d80;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper w1">
  <div class="div-b">This is my really long message hello world hello world hello world </div>
  <div class="div-c">Goodbye world</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper w2">
  <div class="div-b">This is my really long message hello world hello world hello world </div>
  <div class="div-c">Goodbye world</div>
</div>
```

That is enough on Firefox. But for webkit browsers, you may also need

```css
#div-b {
    width: 0;               /* Reduce width as much as necessary */
    flex-grow: 1;           /* Grow to fill remaining space */
    max-width: max-content; /* But don't grow too much */
}
```

Note that `max-content` has much limited browser support, and currently require vendor extensions.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.w1 {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.w2 {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.div-b {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: -moz-max-content;
  max-width: -webkit-max-content;
  max-width: max-content;
}
.div-c {
  color: #6a7d80;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper w1">
  <div class="div-b">This is my really long message hello world hello world hello world </div>
  <div class="div-c">Goodbye world</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper w2">
  <div class="div-b">This is my really long message hello world hello world hello world </div>
  <div class="div-c">Goodbye world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that browser support is limited, though.

Comment: I did try flex, but it doesn't seem to be honouring the max-width of the wrapper. The content is overflowing beyond the 300px width even in your example

Comment: I was on Chrome (on OSX), but just tested Safari and same problem there. FF worked fine

Comment: Can't use flex-grow on #div-b because it will push #div-c all the way to right (even if content in #div-b doesn't fill it up)

Comment: @BillyJohnson That can be fixed with `max-width: max-content`. But it has much less browser support than flexboxes.

Comment: Alas, I have to support IE10 which doesn't seem to support flexbox much less `max-content`

Comment: @BillyJohnson I think IE10 supports an old spec of flexboxes, using `display: -ms-flexbox`.